# Problems while setting up vue-cli

Tags: npm, installation, vuejs2

I'm trying to install Vue-cli environemnt via NPM.

```
npm install --global vue-cli
```

After that I want to create project

```
vue init webpack my-project
```

And I get an error

```
'vue' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've read some solutions, most of them concern changing

**PATH to C:\Users{YourUser}\AppData\Roaming\npm**

Didn't work for me. Can anyone help.

Comment: Possible quick fix: close your command line tool and re-open it, then use the `vue init`.

Comment: Tried it several times.

Comment: did you try install vue-cli with sudo, like `sudo npm install --global vue-cli`

Comment: Are you on Windows like the Path bit implies?

Comment: yuup. Windows 7

Comment: Thanks Bert.. it works. First closed the command line tool and then restart it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, problem was solved by simply deleting everything related to vue-cli installed before. And re-installing vue-cli.

Comment: You should give your solution here instead of only saying you have fixed it.

Answer (score 10):

I follow these commands, It's work fine for me.

```
npm install -g vue-cli

npm install -g vue
```

Edit the System environment variables, and enter the following path, and if still having a problem just try to add a path in System User Variables

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe;

C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Check **vue** installed in **C:\Users{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\npm**
[image]

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Comment: while this solved the problem, they should definitely make it automatic during installation for Windows OS

Answer (score 3):

```
yarn add @vue/cli-service
```

or

```
npm install @vue/cli-service
```

is what worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I have faced simillar issue and re-installing vue-cli didn't work for me. Strange thing is vue and vue-cli get installed successfully but once I tried to create project by using below command

```
vue init webpack myfirstproject
```

I get below error:

```
'vue' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

Tried various solutions but nothing worked for me. Please find my NPM and Node details below:

```
NPM version: 6.2.0
Node version: 8.7.0
```

Actually the issue was "vue-cli" is not supporting to my Node(8.7.0). It requires Node >=8.9. Once I upgraded my Node version. everything is working fine.

```
upgrading your Node version is the correct way to deal with this issue
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this same issue with another possible problem. I had

create-react-app@1.5.2 installed globally

npm list -g --depth=0 will display your globals

I simply uninstalled create-react-app

npm uninstall create-react-app

Vue vue-cli-service now works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue, i deleted my node_modules and re-install and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after searching a lot I found this solution:

You need to Add C:\Program Files\nodejs to your PATH environment variable. To do this follow these steps:

1. Use the global Search to go to "Environment Variables"
2. Click "Edit system environment variables"
3. Click "Environment Variables" in the dialog
4. In the "System Variables" box, search for Path and edit it to include C:\Program Files\nodejs.

You will have to restart any currently-opened command prompts before it will take effect.

I hope it works, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I was installing `@vue/cli` using yarn, i.e. I ran

```
yarn global add @vue/cli
```

Calling `vue` on windows did not work after the installation ('vue' is not recognized as an internal or external command)

What I needed to do was to add `C:\Users\<MY USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin` to path.

Answer (score 1):

`yarn global add @vue/cli` did not work for me

So I removed using `yarn global remove @vue/cli`

Then I installed using `npm install -g @vue/cli` and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

1)Try to remove all the node files, npm and nvm files/folders.

2)Also, remove the PATH of node js and nvm from environment variables.

3)try commands:

```
   node -v
   npm -v
   nvm -v
```

above commands only to make sure that all the entities related to node are uninstalled. 
4) install node, and if necessary install nvm(optioal), then run command

```
   npm install -g @vue/cli
```

above procedure proven to be useful for me. Just give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

for Yarn -> need to install it:

```
npm install -g yarn
```

Installing Vue CLI Package:

```
yarn global add @vue/cli
```

To create project:

```
vue create project-name
```

To run:

```
yarn serve
```

Uninstalling:

```
yarn global remove @vue/cli
```

I follow "npm" package manager instead of "yarn" package manager console because yarn give me a problem while installing it;

command to install Vue CLI:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

For to create Vue project:

```
vue create "project-name"
```

For to run Vue project:

```
npm run serve
```